# Can test case break after changes in lines of code that are not hit by the test case?

Tags: regression-testing, coverage

If I have a test case that passes on one version of the code and a change is made to some lines in the code that are not hit by this test case, is there a possibility that the test case fails after this change? If yes, can you provide an example?
To clarify more: If I have for example a code block as follows

```
    Statement1;
    Statement2;
    Statement3;
```

And I have a test case that only hits Statements 1 and 2. Now suppose a change is made to statement 3 and I need to run the regression to make sure nothing is broken. In that case, does it make sense to run the test case that does not hit Statement 3. Is there any possibility that the test case breaks after the modification?

Comment: Does this behaviour show itself when the test is executed on its own, or only when it is part of a larger test-set? Are you sure the changed code is also not executed as part of starting/setting-up the SUT?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what `Statemen3;` is doing to the overall state of the software. Without you giving more details it is hard to say. At a high level: if `Statement3;` creates some situation where the behaviour of `Statement1;` or `Statement2;` might change, then your test case might fail.

That's why, if you are doing white-box testing (which seems to be the case), it is very important that you have a deep understanding of the code. If you don't, you should ask the developer who wrote (or who is responsible for) the code. They are the best people to answer this type of regression testing question.

Answer (score 0):

Depends with what you mean by *"not hit by this test case"*.

If you mean traditional code coverage, yes, it is possible.

[*Metaprogramming*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaprogramming) allows you to change the structure of code at compile and run-time in ways that may create dependencies in good* unit checks.

[Aspect-Oriented Programming](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/software_testing_dictionary/mutation_testing.htm) changes behavior in a similar fashion.

Also, if you have checks that are integrate or bundle many components, data or expectations may cause [mutations](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/software_testing_dictionary/mutation_testing.htm) to appear in unexpected ways.

Note: These examples are more focused on OOP - other paradigms may have specific situations.

* Well defined boundaries and mocked dependencies.

Comment: I would really appreciate it if you can provide a specific example. I have updated the description for more clarification

Answer (score 0):

If  your test case is not covering the new code, the testcase needs to be changed. Testers need to work closely with developer's to make sure all of the code is executed when the tests are performed.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood what you're asking correctly, one would assume that provided the functionality of statement 3 remains unchanged but the code was just refactored. The test wont fail but it wont necessarily pass as it hasn't covered statement 3.

If you want it to pass for all then you will need to adjust the code accordingly (if required) to match the refactored statement 3.
It comes down to how much coverage you want.

The code change would have to have changed the functionality of the test for it to fail. though it may not cover even if it doesn't.

**TLDR** Long and short. Make sure it hits all the statements and features required for coverage otherwise your test may pass with a false positive.

Answer (score 0):

Depends, If Your changes made effect statement 3 but has some dependency on testcase 1 and 2 , it might break.
You need to cross check with the dependency of code for all the test cases.